# Should I close or delete my question caused by a typo?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just asked this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515669/set-title-of-powershell-window

The solution was that I'd missed out a `.ui` in the command.  A basic typo.

Is best practice to close this question as a typo, or to delete it?

Comment: It's of no use to anyone...I'd delete it before it attracts negative attention.

Comment: If you delete it, it gets deleted immediately. If you vote to close, it'll still need 4 more votes

Comment: That's a terribly generic title.

Comment: That the question arises from a simple typo is one of the standard close reasons, so you should expect your question to be closed and eventually deleted anyway.  It would be community-minded to handle that yourself, and thereby lighten the review queues slightly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Delete. No one will waste time to read it to be sure, that there were point to close it or to vote to close. Also, less number of topic makes easier searching valuable information.